# Android ListView setOnItemClickListener Exception

Tags: android, listview, exception, webview, listadapter

I'm working on an application which parses JSON data from a web service. This data is then stored within a list view and I am trying to enable the application to allow me to click an item within the list. In turn by clicking the item I am attempting to switch activities from the list view into a web view. However when I click on any item within the list the application states that an exception occurred, displays a message stating "Unfortunately [Application Name] has stopped.", and then exit the application.

There are no other issues within the application other than this one. Therefore I would appreciate if anyone could help me to resolve this issue. I have supplied the full body of code from the main activity and the issues occurs within the try catch inside of onCreate, you can also download the application from here: http://bit.ly/17rePw0

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity 
{   
    GPSManager gpsManager;

    ConnectionManager connectManager;

    LocationManager locationManager = null;
    LocationListener locationListener = null;

    AlertDialogManager alertManager = new AlertDialogManager();

    private ProgressDialog progDialog;

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> articleList;

    private String URL_ARTICLES = "http://api.wikilocation.org/articles?lat=56.4607208&lng=-2.9680668&format=json&radius=100";
    private static final String TAG_ARTICLES = "articles";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_LAT = "lat";
    private static final String TAG_LNG = "lng";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "title";
    private static final String TAG_URL = "url";
    private static final String TAG_DISTANCE = "distance";

    private static final int ARTICLE_LIMIT = 20;
    private static int ARTICLE_RADIUS = 100;

    JSONArray articles = null;

    double lat, lng;
    String latitude, longitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        articleList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        connectManager = new ConnectionManager(getApplicationContext());
        gpsManager = new GPSManager(this);

        if(gpsManager.RetrieveLocation)
        {
            lat = gpsManager.RetrieveLatitude();
            lng = gpsManager.RetrieveLongitude();

            latitude = String.valueOf(lat);
            longitude = String.valueOf(lng);

            //URL_ARTICLES = "http://api.wikilocation.org/articles?lat=" + latitude + "&lng=" + longitude + "&format=json&radius=100";
        }
        else
        {
            gpsManager.showSettingsAlert();
        }

        new LoadArticles().execute();

        ListView listView = getListView();

        try
        {
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapt, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }      
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class LoadArticles extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
    {
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progDialog.setMessage("Loading Articles");
            progDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args)
        {
            List<NameValuePair>params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            String json = parser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ARTICLES, "GET", params);

            Log.d("Articles JSON: ", "> " + json);

            try
            {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);

                if(jObj != null)
                {
                    articles = jObj.getJSONArray(TAG_ARTICLES);

                    for(int i = 0; i < articles.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject obj = articles.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = obj.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String lat = obj.getString(TAG_LAT);
                        String lng = obj.getString(TAG_LNG);
                        String name = obj.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String address = obj.getString(TAG_URL);
                        String distance = obj.getString(TAG_DISTANCE);

                        HashMap<String, String>map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_LAT, lat);
                        map.put(TAG_LNG, lng);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_URL, address);
                        map.put(TAG_DISTANCE, distance);

                        articleList.add(map);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url)
        {
            progDialog.dismiss();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                public void run()
                {
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, articleList, 
                            R.layout.list_item_articles, new String[]
                    {
                        TAG_ID, TAG_NAME, TAG_DISTANCE }, new int[]{ R.id.artcile_id, R.id.article_name, R.id.article_distance
                    });

                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added LogCat stack trace.

```
08-03 23:44:02.407: W/dalvikvm(875): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-03 23:44:02.457: E/AndroidRuntime(875): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-03 23:44:02.457: E/AndroidRuntime(875): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.muc2013/com.android.muc2013.WebActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
08-03 23:44:02.457: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
08-03 23:44:02.457: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
08-03 23:44:02.457: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
08-03 23:44:02.457: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
08-03 23:44:02.457: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
08-03 23:44:02.457: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
08-03 23:44:02.457: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at com.android.muc2013.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:99)
08-03 23:44:02.457: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
08-03 23:44:02.457: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
08-03 23:44:02.457: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
08-03 23:44:02.457: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
08-03 23:44:02.457: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-03 23:44:02.457: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-03 23:44:02.457: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-03 23:44:02.457: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-03 23:44:02.457: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-03 23:44:02.457: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-03 23:44:02.457: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-03 23:44:02.457: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-03 23:44:02.457: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post a stack trace from Logcat.

Comment: I see the issue, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are missed to declare another activity in your manifest.xml**

So Android risis this exception

Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.muc2013/com.android.muc2013.WebActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

**Declare this Activity in your manifest.xml file**

```
<activity android:name="com.android.muc2013.WebActivity"/>
```